# In SAS, using ODS TAGSETS.ExcelXP and proc report, how can I adjust bordercolor for ONE column only?

Tags: sas, sas-ods

I have an excel file I want to create from a PROC REPORT step, using ODS TAGSETS.ExcelXP and an adjusted version of the style MINIMAL. I want to have the first column in the output to have white borders (so it doesn't look like it has a border) while the rest of the columns have the black border from MINIMAL still.

I have been trying all day to do it but alas, no success! It is either changing all the borders, or none.

I have tried using

- proc template to edit the minimal style
- style=[bordercolor=white] and all variants to change borders (eg. borderleftcolor etc.)
- style(column)=[bordercolor=white] where this and the one above were tried all over the place in proc report (as a proc report style, as a define style).

Please help! :(

An example output would be like below:

[Example Output](http://tinypic.com/r/2w539cx/8)

Comment: Please include code showing at least one of those attempts so we can see what you're working with, using a built-in dataset like SASHELP.CLASS or SASHELP.CARS.

Comment: If you haven't already, try using `style(column)` in the `define` statement for that particular column only. You can't control style elements on a column-by-column basis in a style; that's for styling _all_ columns at once.